# combine datasets by the value of multiple columns

Tags: r

I'm trying to enter values based on the value of multiple columns from two datasets.
I have my main dataset (df1), with lists of a location and corresponding dates and df2 consists of a list of temperatures at all locations on every possible date. Eg:

df1

```
Location    Date
A           2
B           1
C           1
D           3
B           3
```

df2

```
Location   Date1Temp    Date2Temp    Date3Temp
A          -5           -4           0
B          2            0            2
C          4            4            5
D          6            3            4
```

I would like to create a temperature variable in df1, according to the location and date of each observation. Preferably I would like to carry this out with all Temperature data in the same dataframe, but this can be separated and added 'by date' if necessary. With the example data, I would want this to create something like this:

```
Location    Date    Temp
A           2       -4
B           1       2
C           1       4
D           3       4
B           3       2
```

I've been playing around with merge and ifelse, but haven't figured anything out yet.

Comment: Welcome. Will your `df2` column names exactly match the `df1` date rows? For example, should `Date1Temp` and `1` be the same string or date object? If so, you can transform df2 from a wide data frame into a long one using `melt` or `gather`, and then join the two data frames.

Answer (score 2):

is it what you need?

```
library(reshape2)
library(magrittr)
df1 <- data.frame(Location= c("A","B","C","D","B"),Date=c(2,1,1,3,3))
df2 <- data.frame(Location= c("A","B","C","D"),d1t=c(-5,5,4,6),d2t=c(-4,0,4,3),d3t=c(0,2,5,4))


merge(df1,df2) %>% melt(id.vars=c("Location","Date"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do that with `dplyr` and `tidyr`.

Basically, you want to use `gather` to melt the `DateXTemp` columns from `df2` into two columns. Then, you want to use `gsub` to remove the "Date" and "Temp" strings to get numbers that are comparable to what you have in `df1`. Since DateXTemp were initially characters, you need to transform the remaining numbers to numeric with `as.numeric`. I then use `left_join` to join the tables.

```
library(dplyr);library(tidyr)
df1 <- data.frame(Location= c("A","B","C","D","B"),Date=c(2,1,1,3,3))
df2 <- data.frame(Location= c("A","B","C","D"),Date1Temp=c(-5,5,4,6),
                   Date2Temp=c(-4,0,4,3),Date3Temp=c(0,2,5,4))

df2_new <- df2%>%
             gather(Date,Temp,Date1Temp:Date3Temp)%>%
             mutate(Date=gsub("Date|Temp","",Date))%>%
             mutate(Date=as.numeric(Date))
df1%>%left_join(df2_new)

Joining, by = c("Location", "Date")
  Location Date Temp
1        A    2   -4
2        B    1    5
3        C    1    4
4        D    3    4
5        B    3    2
```

**EDIT**

As suggested by @Sotos, you can do that in one piping like so:

```
df2%>%
  gather(Date,Temp,Date1Temp:Date3Temp)%>%
  mutate(Date=gsub("Date|Temp","",Date))%>%
  mutate(Date=as.numeric(Date))%>%
  left_join(df1,.)

Joining, by = c("Location", "Date")
  Location Date Temp
1        A    2   -4
2        B    1    5
3        C    1    4
4        D    3    4
5        B    3    2
```

Comment: You can keep `left_join` in the piping (`... %>% left_join(df1, .)`)